What kind of sampling should I use to have a representative test set if I have data where n data samples pertain to one measurement?
As my question states, I want to split a dataset I have into train and validation (one subset) and test (another subset).
Usually I would randomly shuffle the data and take a certain percentage of data samples to be my test set, but in this case it is different because my dataset consists of data samples which are formed by taking repeated measurements. In particular, I have 6 data samples pertaining to one measurement, which means that those 6 data samples have the same input features and slightly different predicted value. In other words, the same thing was measured 6 different times.
To give you a visual representation of the data:
I am scared that if I randomly sample (or systematically sample even) I will have a situation where I have let's say 4 or 5 out of 6 data samples pertaining to one particular measurement in the training set and 1 or 2 data samples pertaining to that same measurement in the test set. So basically my machine learning model would have seen 4 or 5 data samples with literally the same input features.
How would I best go about doing sampling for the test set here?
